# Referencing binaries from one project in another

Tags: teamcity

Newbie question : I have 2 C# projects in TeamCity, call them A and B. A contains a reference to B.dll. B builds fine. However, A fails to build because it cannot find B : Could not locate the assembly "B"

It seems really simple : how do I tell my project A on the buildserver where to find the binaries from B\bin\Release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is that Teamcity runs each build in it's own temporary directory and since this is a randomly generated name you can't set a reference directly from one to the other.

Typically you would write a build script that builds both A and B in the right order and just have Teamcity run that build script.  (Since you're using C#, MSBuild is ideal for this).

The alternative would be to have B.dll copied to a known location (e.g. `c:\currentbuild`) at the end of its build and have A always reference it from here.  You can set up build dependencies in Teamcity so that if B is rebuilt, A is also rebuilt.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, I can see the temp directories on the server, and I can create a Build Chain by adding a snapshot dependency. If I could just tell the snapshot to copy the binaries from B into the directory A is expecting, all would be well. Is there no way of doing that? Surely there must be?

Comment: No, I don't think there is.  That is why you should write a build script for TeamCity to execute.

Answer (score 14):

You do this by creating ['Artifacts'](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-ArtifactPaths) and artifact dependencies.

If project A is dependent on project B, then you create an Artifact on project B using an artifact path like so:

```
bin/Release/B.dll
```

Then on project A you setup a artifact dependency on B with path like:

```
B.dll
```

And set the destination path to be where ever project A is expecting to find B.dll e.g.

```
./Libs
```

You can do other cool stuff like automatically archiving all your artifacts into a zip by using the syntax:

```
bin/Release/*.dll => B.zip
```

and access them via:

```
B.zip!B.dll
```

All these paths are relative to build directories so makes it easy and you dont need to worry about the TeamCity guid folders or use absolute paths.